# Mockito thenReturn returns null when coming from generic function

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I want to mock the `ResultSet` in a class, whose parameters come from a generic return function (`getSQLValue`):

```
public class MyClass{

    TableClass clsTableClass;

    public void getResults(Integer index, Integer value, String str) throws SQLException {

        try (ResultSet rsResult = clsTableClass.getRecords(
                getSQLValue(index, value, -1),
                getSQLValue(index, str, "")))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    private <T> T getSQLValue(Integer index, T t, T def) {
        return (index> 0) ? def : t;
    }
}
```

The table class with the signature method:

```
public class TableClass {

    public ResultSet getRecords(Integer value, String str)  {
        // do stuff
    }
```

And this is the unit test class:

```
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock(name = "clsTableClass")
    TableClass clsTableClass;
    @InjectMocks
    MyClass clsMyClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testClass() throws Exception
    {
        ResultSet rsResult = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);

        when( clsTableClass.getRecords(
                any(Integer.class),
                any(String.class)).thenReturn(rsResult);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `ResultSet` is always null, I can confirm when debugging.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out that `Mockito`, after "accepting" the first argument as Integer, fails to aceppt the second argument as String. The solution (after much debugging) is to **cast** the `any()` matcher in the test function to the corresponding class type:

```
@Test
public void testClass() throws Exception
{
    ResultSet rsResult = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);

    when(clsTableClass.getRecords(
            (Integer) any(),
            (String) any()).thenReturn(rsResult);
}
```

Now `Mockito` will match the parameters and the `ResultSet` will no longer return `null`.